# Move gradle temporary cache dir to other directory

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I have some trouble with the temporary gradle cache directory. 
Gradle downloads all dependencies at first to /tmp/gradle_download...bin before it moves them to their target directory.

```
10:55:12.932 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor] Downloading https://${myNexusURL}/nexus/content/groups/../myArtefact.zip to /tmp/gradle_download1430290155040442921bin
```

Our space on /tmp is very limited but on other directories we have enough space. 
Is there a way to change that directory?

```
./gradlew -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-08-15 13:15:01 UTC
Revision:     ad76ba00f59ecb287bd3c037bd25fc3df13ca558

Groovy:       2.4.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_91 (Oracle Corporation 25.91-b14)
OS:           Linux 3.0.101-0.40-default amd64
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by the OP in his own answer, the temporary directory used by Gradle can be set via the `java.io.tmpdir` system property. Maybe the following is obvious but just in case: you can also configure this system property with [an environment variable for Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html#sec:cli_environment_variables) so that you don’t have to separately configure it with each Gradle call.

For example, you could add the following to your `.bashrc`:

```
export GRADLE_OPTS=-Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/tmpdir
```

`GRADLE_OPTS` should be recognized by both `gradle` and the Gradle Wrapper (`gradlew`).

Answer (score 1):

Solving it via -Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/tmpdir